# `createpsbt` RPC call doesn't provide PSBT inputs & outputs

Tags: bitcoin-core, bip174-psbt

I'm attempting to create a PSBT using RPC:

```
bitcoin-cli createpsbt [[{"txid": "1d76879500aecafde541770b5d44ccec5955b4c1a455fae446bf1df7b5ea43e9", "vout": 0}, {"txid": "e5a8dfa9459ac154fe62652e1d43049dae13f11815da36cc32881e27917a0dff", "vout": 1}], [{"bcrt1qnv3tl3z9cll9faqf79ppfn3rrp7pn9wwmq04p5gqgqtxg55xfxuslkyk94": "0.20000000"}, {"bcrt1qa4h6amsgyc878k094grqh6ktmgvp97dt6et9cy5hjmyxlgd9q63q3p6hch": "1.79900000"}], 0, true]
```

This is the PSBT I receive in return:

```
cHNidP8BALICAAAAAulD6rX3Hb9G5PpVpMG0VVnszERdC3dB5f3KrgCVh3YdAAAAAAD9/////w16kSceiDLMNtoVGPETrp0EQx0uZWL+VMGaRanfqOUBAAAAAP3///8CAC0xAQAAAAAiACCbIr/ERcf+VPQJ8UIUziMYfBmVztgfUNEAQBZkUoZJuWAOuQoAAAAAIgAg7W+u7ggmD+PZ5aoGC+rL2hgS+avWVlwSl5bIb6GlBqIAAAAAAAAAAAA=
```

When decoded, the `inputs` and `outputs` sections of the PSBT are empty. Why is this? Bitcoin Core should know everything necessary to fill these sections out. Why doesn't it?

```
bitcoin-cli -regtest decode <psbt>
{'inputs': [{}, {}],
 'outputs': [{}, {}],
 'tx': {'hash': 'fd88b50ec52948dcf04b0d802000b325f960f3333cff8bf7a274273c9d7e2ed7',
        'locktime': 0,
        'size': 178,
        'txid': 'fd88b50ec52948dcf04b0d802000b325f960f3333cff8bf7a274273c9d7e2ed7',
        'version': 2,
        'vin': [{'scriptSig': {'asm': '', 'hex': ''},
                 'sequence': 4294967293,
                 'txid': '1d76879500aecafde541770b5d44ccec5955b4c1a455fae446bf1df7b5ea43e9',
                 'vout': 0},
                {'scriptSig': {'asm': '', 'hex': ''},
                 'sequence': 4294967293,
                 'txid': 'e5a8dfa9459ac154fe62652e1d43049dae13f11815da36cc32881e27917a0dff',
                 'vout': 1}],
        'vout': [{'n': 0,
                  'scriptPubKey': {'addresses': ['bcrt1qnv3tl3z9cll9faqf79ppfn3rrp7pn9wwmq04p5gqgqtxg55xfxuslkyk94'],
                                   'asm': '0 '
                                          '9b22bfc445c7fe54f409f14214ce23187c1995ced81f50d100401664528649b9',
                                   'hex': '00209b22bfc445c7fe54f409f14214ce23187c1995ced81f50d100401664528649b9',
                                   'reqSigs': 1,
                                   'type': 'witness_v0_scripthash'},
                  'value': Decimal('0.20000000')},
                 {'n': 1,
                  'scriptPubKey': {'addresses': ['bcrt1qa4h6amsgyc878k094grqh6ktmgvp97dt6et9cy5hjmyxlgd9q63q3p6hch'],
                                   'asm': '0 '
                                          'ed6faeee08260fe3d9e5aa060beacbda1812f9abd6565c129796c86fa1a506a2',
                                   'hex': '0020ed6faeee08260fe3d9e5aa060beacbda1812f9abd6565c129796c86fa1a506a2',
                                   'reqSigs': 1,
                                   'type': 'witness_v0_scripthash'},
                  'value': Decimal('1.79900000')}],
        'vsize': 178,
        'weight': 712},
 'unknown': {}}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not supposed to. `createpsbt` does not have access to the wallet so it cannot fill in any input or output information. If you want those to be filled in, you can use `walletcreatefundedpsbt`.

Comment: Or alternatively, `utxoupdatepsbt` after `createpsbt` (but that only works for known-to-be-segwit inputs, as pre-segwit inputs need the full transaction that created the output being spent from, something the UTXO set doesn't have access to).

Comment: Ahh I didn't realize it didn't have access to the wallet. This makes perfect sense. Thanks.